# Over MaxStringContentLength?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, asmx

I have some .asmx webservices, imported as service reference on .NET 4.5.

They download a XML string, and than I try to process it with `XmlDocument`.

Well, now I get this error: *The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader*

How can I fix this trouble? I am on Visual Studio 2010, tried [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/niemguy/archive/2007/12/11/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-maxbuffersize-and-maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx), but is WCF, I can't find that zone.

Tried adding this code before calling a function of the webservice:

```
XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myConf = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
myConf.MaxStringContentLength = 202400;
```

but nothing changes!

Comment: Can you post some of your code that calls to the web service?  Did you add it as a service reference, are you using SoapClient or WebClient, a third party library?

Comment: I'm using Service reference. The code is such as call a function of the instance of the webservice, nothing more!

Comment: Service references are actually using WCF under the hood, so your link to that article is exactly what you need.  If you are still having trouble, post a snippet of your app.config / web.config of your bindings an and service client endpoints.

Comment: In fact, I've find the value `maxStringContentLength` inside the webconfig, and change that value. Why are you saying "you are actually using WCF"? When I import I see .scinfo files and .wsdl! I use to know they are .asmc, aren't they?

Comment: Do you also see a Reference.cs file (in the Service Reference directory)?  This is generated by a tool called svcutil that generates WCF client code from a WSDL.

Comment: As specified in the article to which you linked, make sure you are setting all three values (maxStringContentLength, maxBufferSize, and MaxReceivedMessageSize) in your web.config as high as you need.  Also make sure that your endpoint is properly referencing the binding configuration that contains the changed three values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the MaxStringContentLength from you configuration or when you create the binding. Besides that it has to be the same on the server and client. If not you can send it, but not receive the content.